# Replacement of HTC files

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, xhtml, html-components

I am working on a project which is using HTML Components files (.htc), now i want to upgrade the project that should work on all the browsers with IE10, as htc files are no longer supported by IE10. So Please give me solution how we can convert the part of project where we are using htc files. please refer below code:

```
this.Style.Add("BEHAVIOR", "url(xyz.htc)");
```

I want to replace this htc file and code written inside this file. What should needs to be put in replacement of htc file.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Update .htc (HTML Components) custom attributes to js since IE10 standard mode doesn't support htc.

Check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/525495/Update-htc-HTML-Components-custom-attributes-to-js)

Edit :

```
var Method_Behavior = {
    get: function () {
        return this.style.behavior
    },
    set: function (val) {
        this.style.behavior = val
    }
}

//input
if (!HTMLInputElement.prototype.hasOwnProperty("Behavior")) {
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLInputElement.prototype, "Behavior", Method_Behavior);
}
```

Then in the Html page

```
<script src="new_js_file_name" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loaded() {
            document.getElementById("Id_Name").Behavior = "new_behavior";
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: So what should i write in place of   this.Style.Add("BEHAVIOR", "url(xyz.htc)");

Comment: whatever contents of your htc file, it to be written in js file and then use it under script tag

Comment: Ok its fine but how i populate js file on style.add like i did for htc file. Please reply

Comment: call another js file function and keep the style in a variable and then update it. or else you can change it in html directly by calling the js function.

Comment: Can u pls write the code which u explained. It would be helpfull. Thanks a  lot.

Comment: can you tell me the content of xyz.htc?

Comment: Its just setting the css values to elements.